# How to ingest data from HANA to postgres?

Tags: postgresql, etl, hana

This is a very basic question, but I am new to Postgres and want to ingest some data from HANA views. Something like:

```
1. Run queries/stored procedure to extract/join data stored in HANA 
2. Bring into Postgres database
```

I have pulled data from HANA through in SQL Server with `Linked Server` before but despite googling how to do it in postgres.. I can't find too much beyond paid etl solutions.

Would much appreciate pointers on best ways to do it, thank you!